# JavaScript syntax highlighing with wtp eclipse, versions issue

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-wtp

Moving from Eclipse 3.7(Indigo) to Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). Have WTP installed on both, with JSP editor, different versions of WTP (3.3.2 vs 3.5.2) 
Got a problem with javascript syntax highlighting in new version, in jsp. Javascript isnt highlighted if its within html comment.

Compared all possible settings but couldnt find how to solve this question. There's chance i didnt install something additional for that but have no idea what, would appreciate any suggestions.

Screenshots of both versions: 
[image: old highlighting]

[image: new highlighting]